# Solving the equation $y+xy^2-e^{xy}=0$ to form $y=f(x)$.

Tags: analysis

I need help by this question. Problem I don't know where to start by solving such a questions.

Can the equation $y+xy^2-e^{xy}=0$ in a neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ with $x_0=0$ and suitable $y_0$ be brought to the form $y= f(x)$? If yes, what is $f^\prime(0)$?

Comment: If yes, can you tell what $y_0=f(0)$ must be? Because that's a first step to understanding what's going on.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function) might help

Comment: Can you precise the context? Is it an exercise?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second part you can determine the derivative when $x=0$.

Note when $x=0$ we get:

$$y+0\times y^2-e^{0\times y}=0$$

$$y-1=0$$

$$y=1$$

Then to find the derivative at the point $(0,1)$ you can implicitly differentiate your original expression:

$$y'+y^2+2xyy'-e^{xy}(y+xy')=0$$

Substituting in $x=0$ and $y=1$ gives:

$$y'+1-e^0=0$$

$$y'=0$$

Edit:

For reference here is what the graph looks like.

[image]